# Cómo importar un backup de SQL Server en Linux con DBeaver

Tags: sql-server, linux, importación, dbeaver

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo importar o restaurar un backup (extensión .BAK) de SQL Server en Linux.

He instalado SQL Server en Linux sin problemas, y uso DBeaver para conectarme y ver las bases de datos, crear bases de datos nuevas, tablas, etc. Pero DBeaver no tiene, o al menos no la veo, la opción de importar una base de datos desde un backup.

En la imagen se puede ver como con DBeaver tengo acceso a las bases de datos SQL Server que tengo creadas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo he intentado usando este código:

```
USE master RESTORE DATABASE DatabaseName FROM 
DISK = N'C:\FolderName\BackupName.bak' WITH  FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10
```

Pero recibo el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como si el sistema tratara de ubicar el archivo fuente de la base de datos en una ruta de Windows, cuando lo que estoy usando es Linux,  incluso la base de datos UNIVERSAL fue creada desde Linux con el comando "create database UNIVERSAL"

¿Es posible que el proceso de importación tenga que hacerse de otra manera?

Si realizo el mismo intento pero por consola usando Sqlcmd obtengo el mismo error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y si corres ese código por consola usando sqlcmd? Supongo que también existe en la versión para Linux :)

Comment: Hola, si también lo he intentado, pero obtengo el mismo mensaje de error.

Comment: He modificado la pregunta para agregar también lo que me sale por consola cuando uso Sqlcmd

Comment: Hmmm, ya veo, cómo generaste ese backup y en dónde? Es posible que no esté intentando restaurar el contenido sino que esté buscando los datafiles como estaban en la BD origen para actualizarlos.

Comment: El backup lo generé desde Windows, en el Management Studio, con la opción de crear backup, y generé u archivo .BAK

Answer (score 1):

En Windows, este comando funciona bien

```
USE master RESTORE DATABASE DatabaseName FROM 
DISK = N'C:\FolderName\BackupName.bak' WITH  FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10
```

En entornos GNU/Linux

```
USE master RESTORE DATABASE DatabaseName FROM 
DISK = N'Home/nombreUsuario/algunDirectorio/BackupName.bak' WITH  FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10
```

Presta atención a la carpeta y al archivo `.bak` deben tener permisos de lectura necesarios.

Aqui te dejo otro ejemplo

```
RESTORE DATABASE Manvendra FROM DISK='/var/opt/mssql/backup/Manvendra_Full.bak' 
WITH MOVE 'Manvendra' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/manvendra.mdf',
MOVE 'Manvendra_1' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/manvendra_1.ndf',
MOVE 'Manvendra_2' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/manvendra_2.ndf',
MOVE 'Manvendra_log' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/manvendra_log.ldf'
```

Ejemplo extraído de:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4641/restore-a-sql-server-database-on-a-linux-based-instance-from-a-backup-on-a-windows-instance/

Comment: La clave es el MOVE. Tu primer ejemplo es exactamente lo que el op intentó y no le funcionó

Comment: Buen punto, por cierto, nótese la ruta del archivo :D